# Não acha o módulo

Tags: node.js, typescript, módulo-ecmascript

Esse erro que esta dando, estou seguindo um curso e do professor roda, o meu da esse erro!

> ```
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=34110 build\server.js
> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:34110/763e1f04-c0a0-42ad-bcd5-b55004766705
> For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
> Debugger attached.
> Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
> Error: Cannot find module '../env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env.js'
> Require stack:
> C:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\build\config\env\config.js
> - C:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\build\server.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>     at module.exports (c:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\server\config\env\config.ts:4:24)
> at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\server\server.ts:7:46)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
> ```

Comment: Acho que vale **[edit]** a sua pergunta para adicionar um [mcve]. Leia também o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) para saber como este site funciona.

Answer (score 0):

O módulo localizado em `C:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\build\config\env\config.js` está tentando incluir o módulo `../env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env.js`, mas esse caminho não existe. Tente rodar no console o comando `node -e "console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)"`. Se for `undefined`, procure na pasta `C:\Users\Tecnoresolve\Desktop\typescript-course\build\config\env` por algum arquivo que termine com `.env.js` e substitua a string `../env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env.js` pelo caminho desse arquivo.